# Using external variable in LOAD_DATA_INFILE

Tags: python, csv

I have this table structure:

```
date_sourced
sha1
vsdt
trendx
notes
```

And my csv structure: `sha1,vsdt,trendx,notes`

How can I insert a variable value to my `date_sourced`? 
I tried this:

```
var  = "2018-1-10"
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE %s INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (%s,sha1, @var1, trendx,notes) SET vsdt = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM @var1))"
cursor.execute(query, (path,var))
```

but gives me error:

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''2018-1-10',sha1, @var1, trendx,notes) SET vsdt = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LE' at line 1
```

Does LOAD_DATA_INFILE accept external variables? For example I have these two variables

```
import csv
import mysql.connector

path = 'C:\\Users\\trendMICRO\\Desktop\\OJT\\updated_test.csv'

print "CSV importing to database"


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                            host='localhost',
                            database='jeremy_db')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
var  = "apple"
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE %s INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (%s, @var1, person) SET vsdt = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM @var1))"
cursor.execute(query, (path))
mydb.commit()
```

How can I apply it here in my query,by replacing `'path/to/rb'` to my variable `path` and value of `fruit` set by my variable `var = "apple"`?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/rb' INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (fruit, @var1, person) SET vsdt = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM @var1))
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: What is query? Where does cursor come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you are using the MySQLdb module, if you are using a different driver the answer may vary.

To add the values we want to use a parameterized query as follows:

```
var  = "apple"
path = "C:\\apple.txt"
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE %s INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (%s, @var1, person) SET vsdt = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM @var1))"
cursor.execute(query, (path, var))
connection.commit()
```

The parameters stored in the tuple given as the second argument to `cursor.execute()` will be substituted for the values of `%s` that occur in the query string.

Unfortunately this won't work because `path` is not going to be used as a column value, and according to the [MySQLdb user's guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

> Parameter placeholders can only be used to insert column values. They
>   can not be used for other parts of SQL, such as table names,
>   statements, etc.

So we need to do a *horrible* thing and write our query string by hand using the file name. **This is unsafe** if you are allowing user input to be passed in to a variable like `path`.

We can still use a parameter for the value of `var` as before.

```
var  = "apple"
path = "C:\\apple.txt"
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + path + "' "
query += "INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (%s, @var1, person) SET vsdt = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM @var1))"
cursor.execute(query, (var,))
connection.commit()
```

Comment: im using import mysql.connector

Comment: @JeremyAdriandeVera please double-check my edit. Note that to declare a tuple containing only one value, you need to say something like `my_tuple = (var1,)` *not* `my_tuple = (var1)`

Comment: but how can i insert a value in my date_sourced if i dont have that in my csv, look at my edit, I'm only one step to finish this